# How to include ncurses while using Emscripten emcc and make on Mac

Tags: gcc, makefile, llvm, ncurses, emscripten

I'm trying to build a project (namely, Angband's source - http://rephial.org/downloads/3.3/angband-v3.3.2.tar.gz) with Emscripten's emcc in order to port it to Javascript and ultimately build an online version.

I've managed to get the process started with

emconfigure ./configure
make

which begins to successfully start generating LLVM bitcode .o files, but then it hangs up on main-gcu.c with 'main-gcu.c:43:11: fatal error: 'ncurses.h' file not found'

I believe main-gcu.c is the only file that references ncurses, but I just can't figure out how to include the library while compiling. Is there a way to specify including ncurses with 'make', or should I compile the main-gcu.c file individually, with 'emcc main-gcu.c -c -lncurses'? I tried doing that but that led to another error with emcc being unable to find other actually included header files two levels down (it couldn't find headers that were included by a header included by main-gcu.c - anyway to fix that?).

I'm also not certain if I have/need to install the ncurses library on Mac OSX. All I can really find are references to libncurses5-dev for Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you misunderstand the compilation via *Emscripten*. I will try to point out a few problems you are facing.

1. The general rule is that all tools of *Emscripten* **ONLY** can turn ***LLVM* formats** (e.g. *BITCODE*) into *JavaScript*. `emconfigure`, `emmake`, `...` modify the build environment so that your sourcecode is compiled to one of the *LLVM* formats (there are exceptions to the rule but nevermind). So anything you want to link against your final result has to be in a LLVM format, as well (which by default *ncurses* is not).
2. Since the output is *JavaScript*, there is no chance to execute any program code in different threads. While a lot of C/C++ code does use a thread for the UI and others for processing, such a model does **NOT** work for *Emscripten*. So in order to get the software compiling/running you will have to rewrite the parts that use threading. See `emscripten_set_main_loop` for pointers.
3. Even if you have the libraries compiled you then have to **statically** link them to *Emscripten*. At this point it is less of a technical problem but more of a license issue since if your library is licensed under e.g. *LGPL* due to static linking the *GPL* terms are effective.

I hope all clarity finally vanished ;)