# Fatal Error on Compiling the PDF2SVG with Emscripten

Tags: c, pdf, svg, emscripten

For some reasons I needed to be use PDF2SVG (https://github.com/dawbarton/pdf2svg) in browser envoirment; to accomplish that I wanted to use Emscripten. So I followed the steps that described in their site.

But I am always getting this error:

```
    tests/pdf2svg/pdf2svg.c:24:10: fatal error: 'glib.h' file not found
    #include <glib.h>
             ^~~~~~~~
    1 error generated.
    ERROR:root:compiler frontend failed to generate LLVM bitcode, halting
```

I downloaded both required libraries:
Poppler: https://poppler.freedesktop.org/poppler-0.5.4.tar.gz
Cario: https://www.cairographics.org/releases/cairo-1.2.6.tar.gz

And extracted into "pdf2svg" directory.

What do I have to do to pass that error?

Comment: You need to have the developer package (containing header files) of the [glib](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/) library. Debian's package name is for example `libglib2.0-dev`. I don't know which distribution you use, so I cannot tell you the package name for yours. Or you can download the whole library and include it like you do with poppler and cairo. https://ftp.gnome.org/pub/gnome/sources/glib/2.28/

Comment: @Pablo I did what you say and it passed that error, but raise a new one: "tests/pdf2svg/glib-2.28.8/glib\glib.h:32:10: fatal error: 'glib/galloca.h' file not found"... I used this command to compile: "emcc tests/pdf2svg/pdf2svg.c -Itests/pdf2svg/glib-2.28.8/glib" it seems compiler doesnt keep the location of glib directory even if it defined in command line with "-I". How to solve that? Thank you!

Comment: I've never used emcc, so I don't know its command line paramaters. In gcc `-I` is used for additional header directories and when linking `-L` for additional shared library directories, I assume that emcc will follow similar rules. Did you install the glib-dev package or did you download the tarball? Whatever you did, check that `glib/galloca.h` is present in your system.

Comment: Yes, the rules are almost same I think... "glib/galloca.h" is present in the expected directory, however, compiler always throws "fatal error: 'glib/galloca.h' file not found"... I never mentioned that I am using Windows 7, so the compiler might be follow different ways than Linux do...

Comment: Sometimes when you bare include a directory `-I /path/to/include` and the file is `/path/to/include/a,h` but the code does `#include <somelib/a.h>`, then you have to go to `/path/to/include` and create a symlink `somename` to itself (I don't know if windows has symlinks) or you have to copy everything in `/path/to/library/somelib` to match the `#include`. Perhaps this is happening to you, try renaming the folders to match the `#include` path.

Comment: I renamed the include locations whenever an error ocurred, so fixed many location error, but I am stuck with following error this time: "error: parameter named 'glib_major_version' is missing"... As I understand all the constants are defined in "configure.ac" file, but it seems the compiler doesnt load that file automatically. How can I force compiler to include "configure.ac" file on compiling?

Answer (score 2):

**Disclaimer**

I've decided to wrote an answer even though this is not going to give you a
solution to you current problem. The comment section is very limiting and we
cannot have a proper discussion, nor I can give enough details in the comments.

**edit**

I've found this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11075588/1480131). This might also help you with your problem

** end edit **

---

A major problem in your question is that we don't have enough information about
your system: I don't know which distro you are using, which packages are
installed, how you installed them (by hand vs package managers), whether you've
installed the development packages, etc.

Most of the times the way to go is to install the development packages using
the package manager.

Many package today include support for [`pkg-config`](https://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Software/pkg-config/), a tool that prints the
necessary `CFLAGS`, and `LDFLAGS` for compiling and building a package. Sadly
the module names can sometimes vary between distributions. For example on my
system I did the following to get the name of the package

```sh
$ pkg-config --list-all | grep glib
...
glib-2.0                            GLib - C Utility Library

$ pkg-config glib-2.0 --cflags 
-I/usr/include/glib-2.0 -I/usr/lib64/glib-2.0/include

$ pkg-config glib-2.0 --libs
-lglib-2.0
```

Which shows me which `CFLAGS` and which `LDFLAGS` I should use to use glib.

Typically you'll do something likes this:

```sh
$ gcc main.c -omain `pkg-config glib-2.0 --cflags --libs`
```

> Now I've stated in the comments that I personally haven't used `emcc`, so I
>   don't its parameters, but guess is that it will have the same or very similar
>   parameters.
>
> I renamed the include locations whenever an error ocurred, so fixed many location error, but I am stuck with following error this time:
>
> ```
> "error: parameter named 'glib_major_version' is missing"
> ```
>
> As I understand all the constants are defined in `configure.ac` file, but it seems the compiler doesnt load that
>   file automatically. How can I force compiler to include `configure.ac` file on compiling?

Now we are entering in another territory which is the [GNU Build System](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GNU_Build_System),
also known as Autotools. I don't know how much you know about it, but based in
your question, there are some knowledge gaps there.

When writing software, you can either compile it by hand, typing the compiling
commands yourself, or you can use software that automates the process. `make` is
one of this. While it is perfectly fine to write a `Makefile` yourself, it can
be very challenging to maintain a `Makefile` for larger project with different
build options, different targets, cross-compiling etc. That's when people use
yet another software that allows you to dynamically create `Makefile`s. In the
past many open source projects, specially those of [Free Software Foundation](https://www.fsf.org/)
like [GNU](https://gnu.org), use the **GNU Build System** to build their software<sup>1</sup>.

Projects using the GNU Build System have a distinct set of files and scripts that
help programmers maintain the `Makefile`s and makes easy for users to compile
and install them. Typically as a user you do:

```sh
$ tar xpzf someproject-0.0.1.tar.gz
$ cd someproject-0.0.1
$ ./configure --prefix=/usr
$ make
$ make install
```

The `configure` script accepts many more arguments with which you control which
libraries to support, to enable/disable features, cross-compiling options, etc.
`configure` will assess your system determining which compiler you have, which
libraries and their installed versions, etc. If everything goes well, then
it dynamically creates a `Makefile` (out of a template), so that you can run the
`make` command. `configure` does not only create the necessary `Makefile`s, but
also other files that might be used while building the software.

These helper files can be anything, mostly files like `config.h` that defines
macros so that code including `config.h` can see which options are available.
The glib might include other files which for example declare
`glib_major_version`.<sup>2</sup>

So what exactly is `configure.ac`? Now, if you open a `configure` script, you'll
mostly see a ton of code which is not exactly user friendly to read. That is
because the `configure` file is usually not hand written, but it is dynamically
generated by the maintainers. The `configure.ac` is where you have to put the
rules that will affect the `configure` file: things like which language (C,C++,
something else), which libraries, check for dependencies, etc. All in a very
simple syntax.<sup>3</sup>

The command `autoconf` reads the `configure.ac` and generates a new `configure`
file which can be shipped in the tarball. The process is obviously more complex
than that, there are other steps you have to do. Usually `autoreconf -i`
rebuilds `configure` based on `configure.ac` and all the templates needed by
`configure` (like `Makefile.in` templates, which are created from `Makefile.am`
files).

I am telling you all this because of the errors you are encountering. Like I
said in the beginning, I don't know how you installed glib. If there are dev
packages of the libraries for your system, you should install them and to your
`emcc` the proper arguments based on what `pkg-config`<sup>4</sup> tells you.

If that doesn't work and you keep experiencing problems, then I suggest that you
download a tarball of glib and compile it yourself.
Use `./configure --prefix=/home/youruser/projects/whatever` to set the path
where it will be installed, basically somewhere in your home account, so that
you don't accidentally overwrite the system wide glib installation.

Then build glib with `make` and install it with `make install`. Then you have to
pass the correct paths for `emcc`.

The file `configure.ac` should not concern you at all, unless you want to change
something in the `configure` file. In that case you would have to edit
`configure.ac`, make your changes, run `autoreconf -i` to recreate the
`configure` file. Then you can call `./configure && make && make install` again.
But I seriously doubt that you would have to do any of these.

---

<sup>1</sup>Nowadays you see a lot of open source projects using [Cmake](https://cmake.org/),
[Scons](http://scons.org/), etc.

<sup>2</sup>Perhaps as a macro or an inline-function. I haven't looked into the
build files of the glib.

<sup>3</sup>It can get very complex, but still much easier to read as the
`configure` file itself.

<sup>4</sup>When installing libraries in non-defaults paths (like `/usr` or
`/usr/local`i), you have to tell `pkg-config` where to find the `.pc` files that
contain the information read by `pkg-config`. `make install` usually put these
files in `${prefix}/share` (unless you pass `--datadir` or `--datarootdir`
options to `configure`).

So if you did

```sh
$ ./configure --prefix=/home/david/mylibs && make && make install
```

then you have to call `pkg-config` like this:

```sh
$ export PKG_CONFIG_PATH="/home/david/mylibs:${PKG_CONFIG_PATH}"
$ pkg-config glib-2.0 --libs --cflags
```

Comment: Thank you for comprehensive answer! It's like a complete lesson. PDF2SVG became an headache in a project of mine. I've tried it via Java etc. But none of them did a good job, only https://github.com/dawbarton/pdf2svg does... Well I am using Win7 because of several reasons... Now I will be trying to compile with Visual Studio 2017. Does those steps and information you shared kindly will work on VS2017? I am very old for other languages, but new for C :)

Comment: It seems VS2017 wont install into my "veteran" computer... I will try to use "CodeBlocks"...